# Is there a jQuery(&:map) function like in Ruby?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to get all ids from a collection of items, how can I make this one short line:

```
var ids = [];
$(".post").each(function(index, element) {
  ids.push($(element).attr("id"));
});
```

Something like:

```
var ids = $(".post").map("id");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup!  [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) for jQuery objects, or [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map) for arrays and objects.  The jQuery version will return a jQuery object with the map function applied, so you have to call [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to get the actual array out of it.

```
var ids = $(".post").map(function(index, element) { return element.id }).get();
```